# How can I break this while loop once one of the .selections becomes 5?

Tags: java

So I have developed this code for a project which entails creating a program that is a Rick and Morty quiz. I have made a while loop and some if statements but I want the loop to end so I can print something once one of the characters.selections reaches 5 as that is when the quiz will be over. But that is not happening as I don't know how to do that. I have tried making an if statement with a break at the start of the loop but still it doesn't seem to work. Don't mind the incomplete/repeating questions I plan to fix that once I have this problem solved. Thanks in advance!

```
/* Name: Armaan
 * Date: Saturday, November 23rd, 2019
 * Course: Computer Science
 * Description: Rick and Morty quiz
 */

import hsa.Console;
import java.awt.*;

public class RickandMorty {
    static Console c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c = new Console();

        character rick = new character();
        rick.selections = 0;
        //    rick.description = ("");

        character morty = new character();
        morty.selections = 0;
        //    morty.description = ("");

        character summer = new character();
        summer.selections = 0;
        //    summer.description = ("");

        character jerry = new character();
        jerry.selections = 0;
        //    jerry.description = ("");


        while (rick.selections < 5 && morty.selections < 5 && summer.selections < 5 && jerry.selections < 5) {
            if (rick.selections == 5) break;
            if (morty.selections == 5) break;
            if (summer.selections == 5) break;
            if (jerry.selections == 5) break;
            c.print("1. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice = c.readString();
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("2. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice1 = c.readString();
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("3. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice2 = c.readString();
            if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("4. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice3 = c.readString();
            if (choice3.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice3.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice3.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice3.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("5. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice4 = c.readString();
            if (choice4.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice4.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice4.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice4.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("6. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice5 = c.readString();
            if (choice5.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice5.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice5.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice5.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("7. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice6 = c.readString();
            if (choice6.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice6.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice6.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice6.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("8. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice7 = c.readString();
            if (choice7.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice7.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice7.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice7.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("9. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice8 = c.readString();
            if (choice8.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice8.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice8.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice8.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("10. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice9 = c.readString();
            if (choice9.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice9.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice9.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice9.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("11. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice10 = c.readString();
            if (choice10.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice10.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice10.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice10.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("12. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice11 = c.readString();
            if (choice11.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice11.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice11.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice11.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("13. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice12 = c.readString();
            if (choice12.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice12.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice12.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice12.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("14. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice13 = c.readString();
            if (choice13.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice13.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice13.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice13.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("15. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice14 = c.readString();
            if (choice14.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice14.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice14.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice14.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("16. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice15 = c.readString();
            if (choice15.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice15.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice15.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice15.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("17. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice16 = c.readString();
            if (choice16.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice16.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice16.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice16.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("18. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice17 = c.readString();
            if (choice17.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice17.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice17.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice17.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }


            c.print("19. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice18 = c.readString();
            if (choice18.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice18.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice18.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice18.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }

            c.print("20. Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
            String choice19 = c.readString();
            if (choice19.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                rick.selections++;
            }
            if (choice19.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                morty.selections++;
            }
            if (choice19.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                summer.selections++;
            }
            if (choice19.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                jerry.selections++;
            }
        }
    }
}

class character {
    int selections;
    String descprition;
}
```

Comment: You have to check whether a character has 5 after each question. Right now it only checks once per loop, so it has to ask all the questions before it checks again.

Comment: Please use [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), You can extract all of that ifs to functions

Answer (score 1):

There is a principle that says "Don't repeat yourself". As your selection blocks follow the same pattern you can simplify the loop, so it will check the condition once per question and exit when any of the characters reaches 5 (so you don't need the break):

```
String choice;
int q = 1;

while (rick.selections < 5 && morty.selections < 5 && summer.selections < 5 && jerry.selections < 5 && q <= 20) {

    c.print(q + ". Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
    choice = c.readString();

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        rick.selections++;
    }
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
        morty.selections++;
    }
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
       summer.selections++;
    }
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
        jerry.selections++;
    }

    //Do things with 'choice'

    q++;

}
```

If you need each of the choices out of the loop, you can do, before entering the loop:

```
String[] choice = new String[20];
int q = 0;
...
while...

    c.print((q + 1) + ". Pick a fear | A Responsibility | B Spiders | C Death | D Being Alone |");
    choice[i] = c.readString();

    if (choice[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        rick.selections++;
    }
    ...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will check the condition after completing the entire code block. To fix this, just add your `if (selections == 5) break;` checks after every instance where the values of selection could change.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to use >= instead of ==.